# How to show saved tag suggestions back in textbox

Tags: c#, jquery, html, sql

I am using [jQuery tagsly Plugin](http://www.jqueryscript.net/form/jQuery-Plugin-For-Easy-Tags-Input-with-Auto-Suggestion-tagsly.html) to show suggestions in textbox. Everything working fine and I am able to save tags in database.

**Problem:**

How I can show saved tags back in the textbox when i try to update user info.
Suppose when I created new user I had entered

```
Jquery
C#
SQL
```

Now I want to update this user info, at this time I want these saved tags in the same format as I shown in snapshot.

[image]

I have no clue how to do this. Please let me know if you need more clarification. I will try my best to provide asap.

Comment: what you mean retrieve them from the database and display them in the same order? can you explain a little bit more what your actually problem is?

Comment: Hi Josh, I had updated my question. Please go through now. If you still need more information then please let me know.

Comment: i really dont know what you mean? have you got any code? near impossible for me to help here

Answer (score 0):

1- get the tags names from db using an API + ajax call

2- loop the tags

3- simply add the following string after editing it after

```
<span class="tag" data-text="sometag" tabindex="-1">sometag<a href="#" tabindex="-1" data-text="sometag">x</a></span>
```